# Redirect to Angular route from JAX-RS ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: angular, filter, jax-rs

Can anybody please advise, how to redirect to a particular Angular route from a JAX-RS `ContainerRequestFilter`? I read somewhere that I need interceptors on the Angular side to do this.
Can anybody please guide me to some sample code for this?

**Background:**
I have an application where I need to interface with the client's single-sign-on service.
I first send a request from Angular to the service. The service presents the login page to the user.
Upon successfull login, the service redirects to my app with a POST call. This call is handled by a ContainerRequestFilter, in which I extract
user info from the call and create user session. Finally I need to do a redirect back from the filter, to the app's homepage via a particular Angular route. The scenario is like in this pic.  [image]

Currently, at the end of the filter() method in the containerrequestfilter, I'm trying to redirect like this, but it doesn't seem to reach the Angular layer deployed on Apache.

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    
    if (requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath().equals("ssoauthenticate")) {

        // do miscellaneous steps related to user session creation
 
        requestContext.setRequestUri(URI.create("https://helloworld.net/MyApp/#/home"));
        
        return;     

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
requestContext.setRequestUri(URI.create("https://helloworld.net/MyApp/#/home"));
```

This does absolutely nothing. All you are doing is setting the URI for the current request. This URI is for server uses only. If you want a real redirect, what you want is to use the HTTP redirect protocol which consists of a 303<sup>1</sup> status code and a `Location` header with the URI to redirect to. To implement this in a `ContainerRequestFilter`, you abort the request with a `Response`.

```java
requestContext.abortWith(
        Response.seeOther(URI.create("https://helloworld.net/MyApp/#/home"))
                .build());
return;
```

This will set the status to [303](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303) and set the `Location` header to the one you specify. If the browser is working correctly, the user should be redirected to the URI.

---

<sub>1. There are other redirect status codes (all in the 3xx family).</sub>